# Django: how to get a URL view name from a request?

Tags: python, django

In Django url configs, you can use url "view names" to aid various activities like redirects. Seen here in this example `urls.py` file (the final `name` arguments):

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_view, name='home'),
    path('search/', views.search_view, name='search'),
    ....
```

Now, in my Django view function, I would like to inspect the current `request` object to discover the current url "view name" for the current request. This could be useful to create a general-purpose "handler" function that could be called from multiple views (or better yet to use in a view decorator).

This would allow your general purpose function to redirect to the current page on a POST request for example. But to redirect via `redirect()` requires knowing the "view name" you want to redirect to.

How can I find the "view name" by inspecting the current `request`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can discover the current url "view name" by calling `resolve()` passing the current request path. That returns a `ResolverMatch` object which has a `view_name` property containing the current "view name".

```py
from django.urls import resolve

def my_view(request):
    current_view_name = resolve(request.path).view_name
```

then you could redirect similar to…

```py
return redirect(current_view_name, **kwargs)
```